# Logstash GeoIP on X-Fowarded-for

Tags: linux, apache, logstash

We are using logstash and it's grok filtering to pre-process our Apache Logfiles.
All our machines are behind load balancers, so client IPs are logged into the "X-Forwarded-For" header.

Our access logs look like this:

```
"18.32.120.32, 192.168.12.118" [07/Sep/2014:15:53:48 +0200] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 137 "http://www.google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
 "18.32.120.32, 88.32.240.21, 192.168.12.118" [07/Sep/2014:15:53:48 +0200] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 137 "http://www.google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"
```

the corresponding apache logging directive looks like this:

```
LogFormat       "\"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"
```

As you can see, the x-forwarded-for header can consist from 1 to 3 IP Addresses, depending on the way the request is received.

We interpret the **x-Forwarded-for** header as "QuotedString" in the logstash/grok pattern:

```
CUSTOMLOG %{QUOTEDSTRING:xforwardedfor_header} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] %{HOSTNAME:host_header} \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QUOTEDSTRING:http_referrer} %{QUOTEDSTRING:http_useragent}
```

If we try to use the GeoIP Module from grok on the xforwardedfor_header field, the geo resolution fails. Shouldn't the module search and use the first IP Address it encounters?

Do we need the interpret the x-forwarded-for entry another way? If so, how?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `geoip` source code, it does hanlde an array:

```
     ip = event[@source]
     ip = ip.first if ip.is_a? Array
```

So that tells me that you don't have an array in your xforwardedfor_header -- you have a comma seperated string... so you just need to [split](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/split) it.

```
filter {
  split {
    field => xforwardedfor_header
    terminator => ','
  }
}
```

Doing that before your `geoip` filter should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Alcanzar. Seems to work now, but only for v4 addresses.
For the v6 Adresses i get an "invalid IP or hostname" error.
Seems like logstash isn't supporting the GeoIP V6 database.

Comment: ipv6 fix seems to be on the fix list for 1.4.3 of logstash ;)
https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/pull/1350

Comment: I've got an error message "Unknown setting 'source' for split", :level=>:error

There's no source here, http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/split .

Comment: I am working on a similar issue but finding `split` is an output multiplier. If I have two IP addresses in my X-Forwarded-For field then I have two output records for the one input record. Is there a way of splitting without creating additional output records or should I be looking for another approach?

Comment: not positive it's the only way, but you could just use a ruby filter:`ruby { code => "event['whatever'] = event['whatever'].split(",")" } `